# An error about my Anjular js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

everyone, I am new to Angular Js. I just try to run this code and it occurs a problem which is "angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]." 
I can't find what the promblem it is. Can you help? Thanks a lot.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--The ngApp (ng-app) directive is applied to
specify the root of the application-->
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--The ngInit (ng-init) directive is used to
            – Evaluate an expression
            – Initialize a JavaScript variable-->
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="media-list">
                    <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes"> <!--dishes is the array, dish is used by the following expression-->
                        <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}</h2>
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                            <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                            <p>Type your comment:
                                <!--The ngModel directive binds the input value to a variable within the scope-->
                                <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment"></p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("confusionAPP",[]); //此处module名字和ng-App处是同一个名字
        app.controller("menuController",function() {
           var dishes = [{
                name:'Uthapizza',
                image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                category: 'mains',
                label:'Hot',
                price:'4.99',
                description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                comment: ''
            },
                {
                    name:'Zucchipakoda',
                    image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'Vadonut',
                    image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                    category: 'appetizer',
                    label:'New',
                    price:'1.99',
                    description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                    comment: ''
                },
                {
                    name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                    image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                    category: 'dessert',
                    label:'',
                    price:'2.99',
                    description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                    comment: ''
                }
            ];
            this.dishes = dishes;
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably a module is missing. To know which module is missing, use the non minified angular.js. So it will give a readable error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">
```

Into this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionAPP">
```

It must match the JS code

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks, and one more question is why the controller needs "this.dishes = dishes;" in the bottom of the code to make dishes available to html code, why the "dishes" can not be directly used by html code after it is defined in controller?

Comment: You are iterating over menuCtrl.dishes, the var inside the scope of the menuCtrl does not belong to the menuCtrl itself but to its scope in JS. You should look how to use $scope: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope Then you can just use `dish in dishes` while on the JS side you do `$scope.dishes = [dishes]` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put same name of your module name in html and js code both.
Here your module name is **confusionAPP** so you need to write same name in html also.

so chagne line from

> < html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

to

> < html lang="en" ng-app="confusionAPP">

now it works.